# Customize Lookup Field Search Results

Tags: lightning, lookup, search

I'm having difficulty configuring the Lookup list reference in lighting. For example in the image below I would like to set different fields per each object to make the search results more relevant.

[image]

I found the following documentation in reference to this question: [Configure Lookup Search Results in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_lookup_config_lex.htm&type=5)

Even after setting my custom field choice as the 2nd usable field it doesn't appear to be taking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One over-sight I had from the [Salesforce Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_lookup_config_lex.htm&type=5) was the following:

> - *Examples of **usable** fields are **short-text, phone, currency, percent, date, or time fields**.*
> - *Examples of **unusable** fields are HTML-formatted fields (URL and email), inline image fields, pick lists, or long-text fields.*

Therefore the field of choice **must be a USABLE field type**. With that said, a workaround I found with this was to create a formula text field that concatenates the values I would like to see. The beauty of this solution is you could setup each object with an `Identifier__c` field that contains logic to provide the best identifier information available on the record. For example something like the following could allow for a more flexible help field.

```
IF(  NOT(ISBLANK( ShippingStreet )), ShippingStreet + ', ' + ShippingCity + ', ' + ShippingState,
   IF(  NOT(ISBLANK( Some_Field__c )), Some_Field__c, 
      IF(  NOT(ISBLANK( Some_Field2__c )), Some_Field2__c, '')
   )
)
```

Be sure once you create the field you add it to you search results

[image]

[image]